# How to insert Hotjar code to a laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, hotjar

i have a Laravel project with the usual file structure (see below)

[image: File Structure]

and i am trying to run Hotjar for insights on the user experience.

Hotjar requires me to insert the following code in the html  tag to be able to track customers interactions with site usability and for feedback.

```js
<!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for sgmh10.brighton.domains/hbgroup/public -->
<script>
    (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:1291660,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
</script>
```

however across all my laravel folder i don't have HTML  file

i am new to Laravel could anyone help with this please.

Many thanks

Comment: Meant i don't have html <head> tag across all project.

Comment: You can add it in `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

Comment: If you don't have the file above yet, you could publish it using `php artisan make:auth`. The command would create a base layout for your application.

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the bottom of your layout blade file, so it will be available on every page of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add this on your homepage instead of a page protected by authentication.

You can go to `resources/views` directory, you will find a `welcome.blade.php` file. Open that file and then you can paste the contents in there.